# Matrix exponential of a skew-symmetric matrix without series expansion

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential, skew-symmetric-matrices

I have the following skew-symmetric matrix

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}   0 & -a_3 &  a_2 \\
                     a_3 &    0 & -a_1 \\
                    -a_2 &  a_1 &    0 \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I compute $e^{C}$ without resorting to the series expansion of $e^{C}$? Shall I get a finite expression for it?

NB:  Values of $a_i$ s can't be changed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $x = \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}$. You can verify that $C^3 = -(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)C = -x^2C$.

Hence, $C^{2m+1} = (-1)^mx^{2m}C$ and $C^{2m} = (-1)^{m-1}x^{2m-2}C^2$.

Therefore, $e^C = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!}C^n = I + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2m+1)!}C^{2m+1} + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2m)!}C^{2m}$

$= \displaystyle I + \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^mx^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}C + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{m-1}x^{2m-2}}{(2m)!}C^{2}$

$= \displaystyle I + \dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^mx^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}C - \dfrac{1}{x^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{m}x^{2m}}{(2m)!}C^{2}$

$= I + \dfrac{\sin x}{x}C + \dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}C^2$

Comment: Thanks... May I ask you one question is this $e^x$ is applicable to matrices of 3d and more

Comment: For any square matrix $A$, we define $e^A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}A^n$.

Comment: That is fine..Agreed...I have a case where matrices of 3D and 4D involved..Will that satisfy that dimension too..?

Comment: What do you mean by matrices of 3D and 4D? Are you talking about tensors?

Comment: yes I meant tensors

Comment: There is a connected question I needed from it. You can check the [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879380/series-expansion-involving-matrix-exponent)!

Answer (score 5):

A geometric proof.

$C$ is the matrix of $u\in \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow a\times u$ where $a=[a_1,a_2,a_3]^T$. $\exp(C){\exp(C)}^T=I$ and $\det(\exp(C))>0$ ; then $\exp(C)\in O^+(3)$, that is a rotation $\exp(C)=R=Rot(\Delta,\theta)$. Note that $Ca=0$ implies $Ra=a$ and $\Delta$ is the oriented line defined by $a$.

After some calculations, $Trace(R)=1+2\cos(\theta)=1+2\cos(||a||)$. Moreover, let $b=[a_2,-a_1,0]^T$ ($b$ is orthogonal to $a$) ; we obtain $\dfrac{1}{{a_1}^2+{a_2}^2}||b\times Rb||=\sin(||a||)$. Conclusion $\theta=||a||$.

Comment: What is $u$ and $a$ here? and is $\|u\|= 1$?

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\tss{\mathop{\bigotimes}\limits}
\def\dss{\mathop{\odot}\limits}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\notimplies{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}
$The following method can be utilized even if you do not have access to a simple series definition of the function but are able to evaluate it for any value in its domain by some black-box method.

The first insight is that, as a consequence of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, any analytic function of an $n\times n$ matrix is equal to a polynomial of degree $(n-1)$ with scalar coefficients.

For example, in the case of the matrix $C$ above
$$f(C) = \b_0 I + \b_1C + \b_2C^2$$
The problem boils down to calculating the $\b_k$ coefficients.

The next insight is that, if $\l_k$ are the eigenvalues of $C$,
then $f(\l_k)$ are the eigenvalues of $f(C)$. Therefore, you can write an eigenvalue version of the polynomial
$$f(\l_k) = \b_0 + \b_1\l_k + \b_2\l_k^2$$
Substituting the eigenvalues of $C$ yields a $3\times 3$ linear system, which can be solved for the $\b_k$ coefficients. The eigenvalues of
$C$ are known to be $\{\pm i\a,0\}$ where
$${
a = \m{a_1\\a_2\\a_3},\qquad
\a = \big\|a\big\|_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\big\|C\big\|_F
}$$

The linear system
$$\eqalign{
&\b_0 + i\a\b_1 - \a^2\b_2 &= f(i\a) &\doteq f_p
 \quad&\big(f\;{\rm plus}\big) \\
&\b_0 - i\a\b_1 - \a^2\b_2 &= f(-i\a) &\doteq f_m
 \quad&\big(f\;{\rm minus}\big) \\
&\b_0  &= f(0) &\doteq f_z
 \quad&\big(f\;{\rm zero}\big) \\
}$$
can be solved by Cramer's Rule to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\b_0 &= f_z \qquad
\b_1 &= \frac{f_p-f_m}{2i\a} \qquad
\b_2 &= \frac{2f_z-(f_p+f_m)}{2\a^2} \\
}$$
Again, these formulas are valid for any function of $C$:
$\;\,$`log()`$,\;$ `erf()`$,\;$ `sinh()`$,\, \ldots$

Let's evaluate the coefficients in the case of `exp()`
$$\eqalign{
\b_0 &= e^0 = \o \\
\b_1 &= \frac{e^{i\a}-e^{-i\a}}{2i\a}
  = \frac{2i\sin(\a)}{2i\a}
  = \frac{\sin(\a)}{\a} \\
\b_2 &= \frac{2-(e^{i\a}+e^{-i\a})}{2\a^2}
 = \frac{2-2\cos(\a)}{2\a^2}
 = \frac{\o-\cos(\a)}{\a^2} \\
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
\exp(C) = I + \frac{\sin(\a)}{\a}\;C + \frac{\o-\cos(\a)}{\a^2}\;C^2 \\
\\
}$$
This idea of eigenvalue interpolation is associated with the
names of$\,$ *Sylvester* $\,$and$\,$ *Hermite*.